# How to deal with C typedef in cython?

Tags: c, cython, typedef

I'm working with the Cuba library and I wish to use the C code in my Cython file. To use the methods I want from header file cuba.h, I am writing at the top of my Cython file

```
cdef extern from "cuba.h":
    void Cuhre(const int ndim, const int ncomp, integrand_t integrand,
    const double epsrel, const double epsabs,
    const int flags, const int mineval, const int maxeval,
    const int key,
    int *nregions, int *neval, int *fail,
    double integral[], double error[], double prob[])
```

Cuhre is the only method I wish to use, and above is its signature. The program is able to locate cuba.h, but it raises an error saying that it doesn't recognize integrand_t as a type. In cuba.h, it defines a function type *integrand_t:

```
typedef double cubareal;
typedef int (*integrand_t)(const int *ndim, const cubareal x[], const int *ncomp, cubareal f[], void *userdata);
```

So, how can I fix this error and use the Cuba library in my Cython program? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `typedef` => `ctypedef` and prepend to your file.

Answer (score 1):

Define your typedef in your cython file as below

```
cdef extern from "cuba.h":
    ctypedef int (*integrand_t)(const int *ndim, const cubareal x[], const int *ncomp, cubareal f[], void *userdata)
```